# Cannot Download String From An Url C# Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, json, windows-8.1

I am new To C# programming.
I want to develop a simple Weather App using openweathermap API's.
I want to download and read contents of a file from an URL.

This is my Code to download file contents:

```
 class WebClientToDownload
{
    string webresponse;

    public async void DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        string baseurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(baseurl);
        sb.Append(url + "&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");
        string actual = sb.ToString();
        HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(actual);
        webresponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();           
    }

    public string StringReturn()
    {
        return webresponse;
    }
```

string passed to the function is the name of city.
This is MainPage Code where I call those functions:

```
 string JSONData;
    private void GetWeatherButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        WebClientToDownload Cls = new WebClientToDownload();
        Cls.DownloadFile(GetWeatherText.Text);
        JSONData = Cls.StringReturn();
        JSONOutput.Text = JSONData;
    }
```

I am getting an error at last line of code says as

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide more detail about the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Do you get an error? What happens when you run the code?

Comment: Sorry I just forgot to add error Details : String webresponce is  null when i try to get data

Comment: Isn't this down to the await?  So you're trying to use webresponse by calling StringReturn before the web request has returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it was down to your use of await.  Basically, await will pass control back to the calling function and allow it to continue until it is awaited, which isn't happening in your case so it is calling Cls.StringReturn() before the data has been returned.  You can change as follows:

In your form:

```
string JSONData;
// Note the async keyword in the method declaration.
private async void GetWeatherButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClientToDownload Cls = new WebClientToDownload();
    // Notice the await keyword here which pauses the execution of this method until the data is returned.
    JSONData = await Cls.DownloadFile(GetWeatherText.Text);
    JSONOutput.Text = JSONData;
}
```

In your download class:

```
class WebClientToDownload
{
    // Notice this now returns a Task<string>.  This will allow you to await on the data being returned.
    public async Task<string> DownloadFile(string url)
    {
        string baseurl = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=";
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(baseurl);
        sb.Append(url + "&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7");
        string actual = sb.ToString();
        HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync(actual);
        // Return the result rather than setting a variable.
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

I've tested and it returned valid data but if any of this isn't clear please let me know.